# how does a computer know which electromagnetic signal to recieve

Tags: networking, ip, wireless

If a computer is connected to the internet wirelessly(eg., fiber connection or mobile hotspot) and is receiving some data in the form of electromagnetic waves, then how does its receiver know which electromagnetic wave to receive. I know that IP address will be used to route the data up to the last transmitter. But when the last transmitter emits electromagnetic waves in all directions, how does the computer know which frequency to listen to.

Comment: It is defined by the Wi-Fi standard.

Answer (score 0):

Communication can be divided into 7 layers theoretically, referring OSI reference model.
Each layer is logically independent.

Fiber connection or wireless connection is the physical layer (Layer 1)
CSMA/CD is the example of layer 1 protocol.

IP address, you've mentioned is the Layer 3 protocol. I mean IP protocol is independent from the physical layer, no matter which technology is used in physical layer.
Physical layer is handled by the network controller IC

PS: Wifi uses ISM band (2.4GHz)
And it is handled by the wifi controller.